# DynamoDB doesn't show updated item data in stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have a DynamoDB table with a stream of type: `NEW_IMAGE`, but i only get new added items to the db in the stream.
I don't get the data of when an existing item was modified.
Is there a way to do this in streams? To send the data of the updated existing items in a stream as well as new items?

Below is my Serverless code

```yaml
OrdersTable:
  Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
  Properties:
    TableName: OrdersTable-${self:provider.stage}
    BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
    AttributeDefinitions:
      - AttributeName: id
        AttributeType: S
      - AttributeName: createdAt
        AttributeType: S
      - AttributeName: ticker 
        AttributeType: S
      - AttributeName: orderRate 
        AttributeType: S  
    KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: id
        KeyType: HASH
      - AttributeName: createdAt
        KeyType: RANGE        
    GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
      - IndexName: ticker_orderRate
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: ticker
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: orderRate
            KeyType: RANGE
        Projection:
          ProjectionType: ALL      
    StreamSpecification:
      StreamViewType: NEW_IMAGE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updates should be part of the stream as well, `NEW_IMAGE` just means that only the changed version will be sent to the stream, i.e. the "after" version of the item.

> `NEW_IMAGE` - The entire item, as it appears after it was modified, is written to the stream.
>
> — [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_StreamSpecification.html)

Note that items need to be *changed* for them to appear in the stream, an `UpdateItem` call that doesn't result in a change to the data won't show up.